# Are copy constructors required for classes which have vector, list or map from the stl as members

Tags: c++, stl, copy-constructor

I am writing a class which uses the stl class map as a member. I have no pointers in the class. Do I need to write a custom copy constructor or will the default copy constructor work fine?

After reading the answers I am adding some more information. I have static const variables but those are not initialized during construction. I have no reference members. Everything else is a 64 bit integer. I also have a map iterator as a member in the class.

Comment: All std::containers will behave well with a default (compiler generated) copy constructor.

Comment: Without knowing was your class **does**, it is hard to say if the compiler generated code is satisfactory. Particularly, do you manage any resource ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default copy constructor will always work (it just calls the copy constructors of all the class members).

Generally speaking, the only time you may have an issue is when you are using members that carry non-trivial construction/destruction (like objects that manage a global resource such as file descriptors for files/kernel services and pointers for memory) that would be (and need to be) cleaned up by the destructor and reallocated by the copy constructor.

I know of some optimizations that can make the copy constructor faster if you implement it, but they aren't really necessary.

Comment: "The only time"? No, there are other reasons why the compiler-generated copy constructor may not do what you want. A trivial example is a class which stores a file handle in an `int` member, and attempts to close that handle in its destructor. The same principle as with pointers, but without actually having any pointers.

Comment: Even though this is the correct answer based on the description I gave. In the end I had to write both a copy constructor and assignment operator because of a slight issue in how the class I wrote and the stl were interacting.

Answer (score 4):

Pointer members aren't the only things that would cause problems here. There are several factors that may require you to have a custom copy constructor, including but not limited to:

- Reference members, as they require explicit initialization
- `const` member variables, same reason
- Any member variables of types that do not provide copy constructors

Comment: No, a class's default copy constructor works just fine even if its member variables don't provide default constructors.  The issue is when a member variable doesn't provide a copy constructor.

Comment: @randomusername: Correct. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way in C++ to prohibit copy of an object of particular type. Well written libraries including STL only allow types to be copy constructable if it is safe and does make sense for that type. So if you can copy it (compiler does not generate errors), then it is safe. It is a good practice to follow this in your own program, even if it is not so big.

Answer (score 0):

The default copy constructor will do fine.